# Submitting a new version to a rejected app on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted an app to the store and it was rejected, let's say the app version is 1.0 and the build is 1, and I have replied to Apple's rejection reasoning through Resolution Centre. The next day I have uploaded a newer version of my app, with version number 1.0, and build number 2. I have three questions:

1- Do I need to click on "Review for Submission" button, after uploading this new build.

2- When I go to Activity -> All Builds, I can see my new build, but with no status, and when I navigate to "App Store Versions", I don't see my new build, is it supposed to appear automatically with "Waiting for Review" status or what shall I expect?

3- If Apple accepted my justification in the "Resolution Centre", before reviewing my new build, this means my old build will appear in the store. What happens after my new build gets accepted, will it also appear on the store, or do I need to increment the app version and resubmit my app for review?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your old build was rejected then it won't ever appear in the store. If it was "metadata rejected" and you have fixed that issue then there is no need to submit a new build; the will approve the existing build. The rejection notification they sent will clearly indicate if a new build is not required.

Assuming that a new build is required, after you upload the new build, it will need to be processed by Apple before it appears in your build list; This typically takes about 30 minutes but can be longer.

Once it has finished processing, go into the relevant "App Store Version", and scroll down to find your existing build,  remove it and then click "add build" and select your new build.

At the top of screen click "save" and then "submit for review".

After Apple reviews and approves your submission it will appear in the store.

Comment: Thank you =) What about question number 3?

Comment: You can only ever have one build for a given version be approved; If Apple have approved the previous build for that version (typically after a rejection state of meta-data rejected is addressed) then you must submit a build with a higher version number to release it.  If they have not approved the previous build then you can submit a new build for the current version.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have version 1.6.0. It is currently in Rejected state. I uploaded new version 1.7.0. But I can't find any possibility to remove current v 1.6.0. Could you help me? Apple support told me, that they can't assist.

Comment: You probably didn't want to upload 1.7.0; All you needed was a higher build number of 1.6.0; You can either do that, or you can go into your 1.6.0 in App Store Connect and change it to 1.7.0 by simply editing the version number.

Answer (score 3):

Update (Aug 2019): After being lost for some time I finally figured out how to submit new build.

I had to go to App Store / App Information. Then I scrolled to General App Info where I changed the version number. Then I removed the build number and selected new build.
Then Save and Submit for review.

Comment: Best answer for the problem I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

delete your rejected previous version then select your latest version to submit

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the rejected version ,then go to the build section, click the build then we got all the information regrading latest version.Then add a new build then click on the save button.It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update (2022-April):

1. Open "General-> App Review" on the left panel and delete the current submitted version
2. Open your current version -> Build then Hover the mouse over your current selected build version -> The delete icon will appear. Click the delete icon to delete the current build version and select another build version